# Getting Error in `Integer': invalid value for Integer()

Tags: ruby

User enters a number, which is to be searched in an array. After that, he/she will enter the size and elements of the array. While writing its solution:

```
number_to_be_searched = gets.chomp #my input=>4
size_of_array = gets.chomp #input => 6
array = Array.new

Integer(size_of_array).times do
    str = gets
    str = Integer(str)
    array.push(str)
end

print array
if array.include? Integer(number_to_be_searched)
    print array.index(number_to_be_searched)
end
```

I am getting the following error:

> in `Integer': invalid value for Integer() "1 4 5 7 9 12" (ArgumentError)

Comment: It would appear that your second input to the program, when it was expecting `size_of_array`, was `1 4 5 7 9 12`. It would help if you showed what your interaction with the program wa when you ran it. What was your input? It would be prudent to have your program prompt (*e.g.*, with `puts`) for each item so you know what it's asking for.

Comment: This is running fine on my machine though the program isn't actually giving back the right search result but I'm not receiving an ArgumentError

Answer (score 0):

```
print 'Number to be searched: '
number_to_be_searched = gets.chomp
print 'Enter size of array: '
size_of_array = gets.chomp
array = Array.new
Integer(size_of_array).times do  |i|
    print "Enter #{i+1}th number: "
    str = gets
    str = Integer(str)
    array.push(str)
end 

p "Numbers you Entered are #{array}"

if array.include? Integer(number_to_be_searched)

    p "Index of found number is : #{array.index(number_to_be_searched.to_i)}"
end
```